# Вызов функции по названию в Python

Tags: python

Мне нужно вызвать различные функции в зависимости от значения переменной b, которая принимает значения от 1 до 3. И у меня есть словарь, с названиями функций, которые мне надо в разных случаях вызывать:

```
{"1" : "first_funk", "2" : "second_funk", "3" : "third_funk"}
```

(Ну или что-то типа того)
Собственно, в этом и есть вопрос, как мне вызывать функцию, не зная заранее ее имя, а беря его из словаря?

Comment: Если это не принципиально, лучше помещать в словарь не названия функций, а сами функции `{"1" : first_funk, "2" : second_funk, "3" : third_funk}` и потом вызывать их как `d['1']()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно использовать globals/locals для этого:

```
functions = {
    "1" : "first_funk", 
    "2" : "second_funk", 
    "3" : "third_funk"
}

globals()[functions['1']]()
locals()[functions['1']]()
```

Или же как написал в комментарии Extrn

> Если это не принципиально, лучше помещать в словарь не названия функций, а сами функции

```
functions = {
    "1" : first_funk, # использую саму функцию 
    "2" : second_funk, 
    "3" : third_funk
}
functions['1']()
```

Answer (score 5):

```
d = {"1" : "first_funk", "2" : "second_funk", "3" : "third_funk"}

method = eval(d["1"])

# Для примера написал только первую функцию
def first_funk():
   print('First function')

# Вызываем функцию
method()
```

Вывод:

```
First function
```

Comment: Что из себя представлет метод eval?

Comment: @Sergo Arkhipov, https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval

Answer (score 1):

```
functions = {"1" : "first_funk", "2" : "second_funk", "3" : "third_funk"}
exec(functions['1']+'()')
```