# Python как можно связать строку с функцией?

Tags: python, функции

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
Часто при создании чат-ботов нужно обрабатывать самые разные команды пользователей и в основном я делаю следующее шаги:

1. Создаю функцию, которая будет обрабатывать определенную команду
2. Принимаю сообщение от пользователя и отправляю в нужную функцию с помощью конструкции if-elif

Но у этого способа один большой недостаток: Нужно городить множественное if-elif, например:

```
new_message = 'персики' 

if new_message == 'клубника':
    get_strawberry(new_message)
elif new_message == 'апельсины':
    get_orange(new_message)
elif new_message == 'персики':
    get_peaches(new_message)
```

И так далее.

Есть ли для избежания этого какой-то способ?

Когда-то встречал в Flask декораторы, которые писались над функциями (которые должны были вернуть страницу пользователю) и в эти декораторы передавались пути на сайте, когда путь совпадал с текущем путём пользователя, то эта функция срабатывала. Но как такое можно реализовать и есть ли у этого название? Чтобы можно было найти информацию или возможно кто-то сможет показать на примере. Так как мне совершенно непонятно, как можно заставить функцию вызваться просто передав "путь" или в моем случае строку в декоратор, написанный над этой самой функцией.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вызов функции по названию в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1072115/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b2-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если хочется через декораторы, то вот пример.

Создаёте в отдельном файле my_handler.py:

```
class Handler:
    funcs = {}

    # Этот метод - декоратор, который привязывает строки к функциям
    def message(self, text):
        def wrapper(func):
            self.funcs[text] = func
            return func
        return wrapper

    # А этот метод обрабатывает сообщения уже после того. как всё привязано
    def proceed(self, text):
        if text in self.funcs:
            return self.funcs[text]()
        else:
            raise ValueError('Unhandled message!!!')
```

А в другом файле уже привязываете ваши функции:

```
from my_handler import Handler

handler = Handler()


@handler.message('strawberry')
def get_strawberry():
    print('strawberry getted!!!')

@handler.message('orange')
def get_strawberry():
    print('orange getted!!!')

@handler.message('peaches')
def get_peaches():
    print('strawberry getted!!!')


# Всё что нужно, привязали, теперь обрабатываем входящие сообщения
# Просто подаёте этому методу на вход строки,
# и он вызывает функцию, подходящую к этой строке

handler.proceed('strawberry')
```

Кстати, декораторы - это не фича именно фласка, а стандартный инструмент самого питона, у которого существуют и другие применения, кроме диспетчеризации сообщений.

Почитать можно, например здесь:
https://habr.com/ru/post/141411/

Или просто погуглить "питон декораторы".

Comment: Благодарю! Это то, что я искал.

Answer (score 8):

Можно хранить словарь ссылок на функции:

```
def default_action():
    pass

actions = {
    'клубника': get_strawberry,
    'апельсины': get_orange,
    'персики': get_peaches
}

actions.get(new_message, default_action)(new_message)
```

Answer (score 1):

упрощу один из ответов:

```
 valid_messages = {'клубника', 'апельсины', 'персики'}
 actions = {
'клубника': get_strawberry,
'апельсины': get_orange,
'персики': get_peaches
}

if new_message in valid_messages:
     action[new_message](new_message)
```

Comment: А потом пользователь пришлёт что-нибудь вроде "песриков" и бот упадёт.

Comment: специально для вас подправил. хотя и не лучшщим образом.
но кто знает  - может варианты из пунктов меню выбираются?
Тогда зачем проверка