# Как сделать отличительные имена для неизвестного количества функций def. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

У меня в программе нужно создать неизвестное количество функций `def` с помощью цикла `for`, для каждой должно быть своё имя. Цикл я уже сделал, а вот с именами функций `def` справиться не могу. Как мне это осуществить?

Comment: уточните вопрос - как вы хотите создать много функций? т.е. тело у функций будет разное? или одно и тоже, но вы хотите вызывать ее под разными именами?

Comment: @Zhihar одно и тоже, но я хочу вызывать ее под разными именами

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия3-8, а как вы их планируете вызывать?? По-моему здесь имеет место ["Ошибка микроскопа-молотка" или "Ошибка XY"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/) - попробуйте описать в вопросе для чего вам это понадобилось

Comment: для связи: [Вызов функции по названию в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1072115/178576)

Comment: спасибо вам большое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

например можно сделать так:

```
def func(value):
    print(value)

for i in range(10):
    globals()[f'myfunc{i}'] = func

myfunc3(10)
myfunc5(20)
```

т.е. добавляем в глобальное пространство имен имя вашей функции и приравниваем ей имя исходной функции

P.S.

недостаток - некоторые IDE (например PyCharm) будут показывать ошибку в редакторе - типа неизвестное имя:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если у меня оригинальная оболочка Python (IDLE), не выдаст ошибку?

Comment: Спасибо, сработало)))

Comment: это показ ошибки только для программиста, сам код работать будет, т.е. предупреждение "не знаю такой функции, потому что такая функция в коде не описана" и лишь при исполнении кода будет в глобальные переменные добавлена новая функция, так что просто по глазам бьет, а на функционал не влияет

Comment: Ааа, понял, хорошо. Ещё раз спасибо

Comment: А подскажите, пожалуйста, как их вызывать с параметром `i`?

Comment: Ну, в смысле, типа: `i=3`, а надо вызвать `myfunc{i}`